# Rewrite C-style for loop in Swift 3

Tags: swift

I have a C-style for loop that's no longer supported in Swift 3.  It looks something like this:

```
for (var x = 0; x < foo.length && x < bar.length; x++) {}
```

What's the equivalent of this that's available now in Swift 3?

Answer (score 2):

if you only need to check the two limits, how about this

```
for x in 0..<min(foo.length, bar.length)
{
    // do stuff
}
```